# Does higher aleph number sets always contain subsets with lower aleph number?

Tags: set-theory

If a set $A$ has aleph number $k$, is there always a subset $S\subset A$ such that $S$ has aleph number $m$, $\forall m\leq k$?

Comment: Subset of one element?

Comment: @herbsteinberg: I think you must have misread the question.

Comment: I guess you meant subsets of all sizes < k.  In that case you run into the continuum hypothesis.  Are there subsets of the reals with members with between reals and integers.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Why do you think the continuum hypothesis is a problem? If the continuum hypothesis is true, there are no cardinalities between those of the integers and the reals. If it is false, there are, and (at least assuming the Axiom of Choice) there are subsets of the reals with each of those cardinalities.

Comment: I'd invite you to add some *context* to the problem statement.  This could be quite simple, such as where you encountered the problem, what makes it interesting or challenging for you, or how far one gets reasoning just from the definition of "a set $A$ has aleph number $k$".

Answer (score 1):

By the assumption that $\vert A\vert=\kappa$, there is a bijection $f:A\to\kappa$. For any aleph number $m\leq\kappa$, let $S$ be the range of the restriction of $f$ to $m\subseteq\kappa$, or the set $\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in m\}$. This is a subset of $A$ of cardinality $m$.

Comment: Your proof does not use choice.

Comment: Are you sure that f(a) can bd defined?

Comment: @herbsteinberg It doesn't matter if f is definable by e.g. some first-order formula, we know that some f:A→κ exists by assumption that A has cardinality κ so we choose an arbitrary f:A→κ and work with that. (This is why I thought the proof used choice, f is arbitrary and we need to perform inverse image on f without first constructing f)

Comment: I have no idea what AC has to do with this. You're already assuming everything in sight is well-ordered.